# Does the wearer know what items are in which patch in the Robe of Useful items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description of the [Robe of Useful Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-useful-items) (BR 195) states that the wearer can detach a patch causing it to become the object or creature it represents.

Does the wearer know which patch contains what object or creature?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## They know... unless they can't see

The [Robe of Useful Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-useful-items) states (my emphasis):

> While wearing the robe, you can use an action to detach one of the patches, causing it to **become the object or creature it represents**.

This implies that there is a visual representation of the item on the patch - making it clear what the item is to anyone that can see it.

This is also supported by the picture in the DMG:

[image: DMG art for Robe of Useful Items]

Comment: To me, though "represents" might not be (completely) visual.  What if the party comes across a robe made by a blind wizard?  Since that wizard isn't going to be able to see his patches, they're likely to be distinguishable by feel - perhaps the "riding horse" is just a circle made out of horse-hair.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse has a good point. 'Represents' does not limit it to sight, it could be texture, shape, smell, or some other way to distinguish them. I do agree that the intent is for the wearer to know which they are using though.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  Such as herbalists using different cord types to tie bags shut.  And/Or different beads on them.  And/Or mixing different strong smelling but harmless herbs with medicines.  All so that they can cross check what they are doing with more than one sense.