# Does the player know exactly what the items depicted on a patch from the Robe of Useful Items are?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am aware of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148020/does-the-wearer-know-what-items-are-in-which-patch-in-the-robe-of-useful-items) detailing whether a character can tell what is depicted on a particular patch on a [Robe of Useful Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-useful-items).

It makes complete sense for the user to be able to tell what *type of item* they are activating otherwise it wouldn't really deserve the moniker of useful.

What I want to know if there is any rules one way or another explaining whether the character would know the *exact properties of the item* the patch will create. For example when picking the random patches rolling a 31-44 determines a patch of a Wooden Ladder (24 feet long). Unless this patch has the words 24ft (or similar) written on it would the character know this was any different to the 10ft ladder available in the PHB list of items?

I have considered asking for an Arcana check to determine how much of the item's nature the character wearing is able to establish but I also don't want to be handicapping the player if there are rules that detail this scenario.

Comment: "It makes complete sense for the user to be able to tell what type of item they are activating otherwise it wouldn't really deserve the moniker of useful." The robe itself makes no claim that it is useful (or, if you prefer, user-friendly); that would be a _Useful Robe of Items_, where you know exactly what the items are, regardless of their utility. That the items themselves were inherently useful would make it instead what it is - a _Robe of Useful Items_.  If you knew what they were before you drew them _and_ they were things of utility, then you would have a _Useful Robe of Useful Items_.

Answer (score 8):

#### You learn after a short rest with the Robe or by casting *identify*.

The rules for [identifying a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#UsingaMagicItem) from the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* say:

> The *identify* spell is the fastest way to reveal an item’s properties. Alternatively, a character can focus on one magic item during a short rest, while being in physical contact with the item. At the end of the rest, the character learns the item’s properties, *as well as how to use them.*

After doing this you know how to use the robe and learn all of its properties. Since producing each item is a property of the Robe, you learn what items the robe produces.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The actual alternative rule is listed as a variant. You might want to state where that quote is from, and the question concerns itself with the notion "exact" which probably warrants some explanation. Specifically, I think the logic of your answer is that the property of the robe is to produce a 24 ft. wooden ladder, not just a wooden ladder. A DM may of course choose to hide the length of the ladder, presuming hoping for a humorous result when the produced ladder is excessively long